# Setting tax on individual items

Tags: paypal, e-commerce

I want to add have tax set on individual items with Paypal. For example, I want "One $1" to have tax @ 12% whilst the remaining "Two $2", "Three $3", "Four $4" and "Five $5" to have tax at 5%.

```
<option value="">--- Or Select a Type of Service ---</option>
<option name="tax_1" value="One $1">Hello $20</option>
<option value="Two $2">Bye $30</option>
<option value="Three $3">Tata $45</option>
<option value="Four $4">Bonjour $40</option>
<option value="Five $5">Au Rrevoir $30</option>
```

Therefore, I use on the form action:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_1" value="6">
```

But it doesn't work for 6% tax for "One $1".  How would I be able to make it work?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="pointblanc@hotmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php if($tutorial_type!="") echo $tutorial_amount_arr[0]; else echo "Gift Certificate" ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Gift Certificate">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php if($amountfull="") echo $tutorial_amount_arr[1]; else echo $tutorialamnt; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="12">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_1" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.testtest.com/thankyou.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.testtest.com">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.testtest.com/ipn.php"/>
<input type="image" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" align="center" style="margin-right:7px; margin-left:150px">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $allcontens; ?>"/>
</form>
```